# Rcpp: taking address of temporary object type proxy, getting a subvector from a CharacterVector

Tags: rcpp

Rcpp question about getting a sub CharacterVector. I have made a rolling window style function that works on multiple NumericVectors, but fails to work when I include CharacterVectors. I get this error each time I try to use a CharacterVector: "taking address of temporary object type proxy".

This is the line of code that causes the problem:

```
  CharacterVector subchrom (&chrom[i], &chrom[i+4]);
```

I am a C++ novice, and thus the solution is beyond me at the moment. From what I have read, the issue is in using the pointer "&" for two different types of vectors, but I don't understand how to fix this. Would someone mind giving me a hand solving this error?

I did a little more reading and now I have a second question. Are "CharacterVectors" in Rcpp programmed as a proxy? This is the only vector type I have this issue with. What is the best workaround?

Here is a full example:

```
#example data for R   
start <- c(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
chrom <- c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1")

df <- data.frame(start, chrom)
```

This is the .cpp Rcpp program:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List modifyDataFrame2(DataFrame df) {

  // access the columns
  CharacterVector chrom = df["chrom"];
  IntegerVector start = df["start"];


  List Out = List::create();

  // write the for loop     
  for(int i=0; i < df.nrow(); ++i){

  NumericVector substart (&start[i], &start[i+4]);
  CharacterVector subchrom (&chrom[i], &chrom[i+4]);

  Rcout << "substart is:" <<substart << "\n";
  Rcout << "subchrom is:" <<subchrom << "\n";

  List temp = List::create(subchrom, substart);
  Out.push_back(temp);

  }
  return Out;
}
```

I am trouble shooting the window function at the moment, hence why it doesn't do anything except print the subvectors. I want to get my input and output from c++ dialed before I complicate things with calculations.

Thank you for your help. I greatly appreciate your time.

Comment: Looking at this table: https://teuder.github.io/rcpp4everyone_en/070_data_types.html#vector-and-matrix It looks like the CharacterVector is a proxy for a StringVector.... Hmmmmm.

Comment: And?  What does that comment have to do with the question?  Answer coming though...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I was curious if that was the cause of the error. Perhaps I need to choose a different method? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making some somewhat heroic assumptions about what you think Rcpp *should* support.  Sadly, it doesn't always work that way with code and libraries.

These "flexible" subsetters are not the strongest are of Rcpp but *some* are supported.  But you need to look at what is actually supported -- I just reminded myself by looking at *existing* tests for subsetting. And one of the oldest methods is indexing by another vector.  As you always want four elements, I just create an index vector ... and then add `i` to it.

Modified code (also corrected on `IntegerVector` to `NumericVector` confusion, and changing the indexing):

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List modifyDataFrame2(DataFrame df) {

  // access the columns
  CharacterVector chrom = df["chrom"];
  IntegerVector start = df["start"];

  List Out;
  IntegerVector ind = IntegerVector::create(0,1,2,3);

  // write the for loop
  for(int i=0; i < df.nrow()-3; ++i){
    IntegerVector currind = ind + i;
    IntegerVector substart = start[currind];
    CharacterVector subchrom = chrom[currind];

    Rcout << "substart is:" << substart << "\n";
    Rcout << "subchrom is:" << subchrom << "\n";
    List temp = List::create(subchrom, substart);
    Out.push_back(temp);
  }
  return Out;
}

/*** R
#example data for R
start <- c(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
chrom <- c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1")
df <- data.frame(start, chrom)
modifyDataFrame2(df)
*/
```

And when I `sourceCpp()` this we get the following:

```
R> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/54190760/answer.cpp")

R> #example data for R
R> start <- c(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10)

R> chrom <- c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1")

R> df <- data.frame(start, chrom)

R> modifyDataFrame2(df)
substart is:0 2 4 6
subchrom is:"chr1" "chr1" "chr1" "chr1"
substart is:2 4 6 8
subchrom is:"chr1" "chr1" "chr1" "chr1"
substart is:4 6 8 10
subchrom is:"chr1" "chr1" "chr1" "chr1"
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "chr1" "chr1" "chr1" "chr1"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 0 2 4 6


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "chr1" "chr1" "chr1" "chr1"

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 2 4 6 8


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "chr1" "chr1" "chr1" "chr1"

[[3]][[2]]
[1]  4  6  8 10


R>
```

Comment: Changing the length of vector ind changes the "window size"? The i < df.nrow()-3 fixes the indexing error that occurs at the end of the vector? Excellent. Thank you.